# Parsing json data to objects in php

Tags: php, json

The url to `JSON` structure

**http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=funny+cat&offset=100&limit=1&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC**

Now I'm trying to parse this `Json` data to my objects:

**this is my class:**

```
<?php
class MappedEntity{
    private $id;
    private $mp4Url;    


    public function setId($id){
        $this->id=$id;
    }
    public function setMp4Url($mp4Url){
        $this->mp4Url=$mp4Url;
    }
    public function getId(){
        return $id;
    }
    public function getMp4Url(){
        return $mp4Url;
    }

    function __contruct($jsonData){
        foreach($jsonData as $key => $val){
            if(property_exists(__CLASS__,$key)){
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

the code thats calling the **class:**

```
<?php

require_once 'mappedEntity.php';


    $keyword = $_POST["keyword"];


    $url="http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=".$keyword."&offset=100&limit=1&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC";



    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $file = json_decode($json);
    $entity = new MappedEntity($file);
    echo $entity->getId();
?>
```

Im getting

**Notice:**

> Undefined variable: id in C:...\MappedEntity.php on line 14

which is following ine

```
13   public function getId(){
14          return $id;
15   }
```

OK, I changed th**e getter methods, and constructor** , now the error goes

```
Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\....\MappedEntity.php on line 14

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:...\MappedEntity.php on line 14
```

I assume , my mapping method inside of constructor is not working fine?

Comment: `return $this->id;`

Comment: 1) Your api key is in that string.

Comment: 2) You are calling `__contruct`, instead of `__construct`

Comment: 3) You need to return `$this->id` not `$id`

Comment: `return $id;` to `return $this->id;` also for  `return $mp4Url;` to `return $this->mp4Url;`

Comment: @filemonczyk what do u want to get from API what should be the output and what are the data you want to store in `id` and `mp4Url`, because there are a lot of mp4 url in api data node

Comment: I want the id of entity, and mp4Url of Original object

Comment: But there are many mp4 urls.  You need to know where the keys are in your data to map correctly.

Comment: I dont actually see the benefit of loading this class. The result of the `json_decode()` will produce an object of `stdClass` that is perfectly usable as it is without adding all this wrapping class which just adds complexity and little or no benefit

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the $this on both getID and getMp4URL functions, they should read:

```
public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}
```

and

```
public function getMp4Url(){
    return $this->mp4Url;
}
```

Comment: and the contructor?

Comment: Firstly fix the typo in the constructor (it should be __construct), you do not need to change the body of the method, it looks okay.

Comment: Except this still wont load the data correctly as the construtor code is also not getting data from the correct part of the structure